# How to pass service bean into spring boot controller using xml configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am not comfortable with annotations. In my spring boot application i am retrieving service bean in controller by application context.(i have skipped the naming convention)

```
Say s1 = (Say) applicationContext.getBean("s1");
```

It seems that my application is tightly coupled with spring, it is making boilerplate code. So is there any way to autowire the service bean into the controller by xml configuration?

i have tried the following way. But i am getting error like "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException". Below i have given code  :

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class Controller_Test implements SpringApplicationContextInterface
    {
         @Autowired
         private Say s1;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/test10")
        public String Test1()
        {
            s1.test();
            return "@RequestMapping(value = test10)";
        }


    }

public interface SpringApplicationContextInterface 
{
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beanConfig.xml");

}
```

**XML config file :**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

        <!--<context:annotation-config />-->

    <bean class="com.fossians.maven_courses.Say"  />
</beans>
```

I have also tried with :

```
<bean class="com.fossians.maven_courses.Say" id="s1" />
```

**Error :**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field s1 in com.fossians.maven_courses.Controller_Test required a bean of type 'com.fossians.maven_courses.Say' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.fossians.maven_courses.Say' in your configuration.
...........................


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller_Test': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 's1'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fossians.maven_courses.Say' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
................................................


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.fossians.maven_courses.Say' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
..............................
```

Comment: Where is your `@ComponentScan`? How do you think Spring will Inject the bean into the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is:

1. First verify that the xml bean file is located in the resource folder.
2. Verify that the bean definition has the id definied

`<bean class="com.fossians.maven_courses.Say" id="s1">`

3. Got to the Main application Class and after the SpringBoot annotation add the import of the bean xml file, in this case I used spring-config.xml

`@SpringBootApplication
 @ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")`

4. Go to the Controller class and Autowired the Application Context

`@Autowired
 private ApplicationContext context;`

5. If you need to get the s1 bean throught application context then use this:

`((Say)context.getBean("s1")).yourMethod();`

6. Also you can Autowire s1 service on your controller

`@Autowired
 private Say sayBean;`

7. You also can use @Service annotation in your Say class and autowired to the controller, that depends on your needs.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to get the `applicationContext`:

```
@Component
public class SpringUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        if (SpringUtil.applicationContext == null){
            SpringUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }
    }

    //获取applicationContext
    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(){
        return applicationContext;
    }

    //通过name获取bean
    public Object getBean(String name){
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(name);
    }

    //通过class获取bean
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz){
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(clazz);
    }

    //通过name和class返回指定bean
    public static <T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> clazz){
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(name, clazz);
    }
```

Then get `bean` with `clazz` or `name`:

```
Say say = SpringUtil.getBean(Say.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code in

```
<bean class="com.fossians.maven_courses.Say"  />
```

in xml to

```
<bean class="com.fossians.maven_courses.Say" id ="s1"  />
```

and see if it makes any difference

Comment: Tried but the result is same

Comment: Please add this to your xml as well  <context:component-scan base-package="path to say class"/>

Comment: sry same...<context:component-scan base-package="com.fossians.maven_courses"/> <bean class="com.fossians.maven_courses.Say" id="s1" />